# Number of passwords

Tags: algorithm, math

I've read this interesting problem:

*how many different passwords made up of **a** upper case letters, **b** lower case letters, **c** digits and **d** characters from this set {'$','%','!','&','@'} exist?*

This could be used to suggest strong passwords.

Comment: Just a wiki type question, answered it myself...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] (combinatorics) instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I disagree! It's relevant to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic combinatorics problem.

First of all, you have two base 26 numbers of lengths **a** and **b**, a base 10 number of length **c** and a base 5 number of length **d**. You have to multiply  the number of these numbers to the number of ways you can arrange them, so you get:

[image]